# how to fix the "__path__ attribute not found" error for packages installed by pip installer?

Tags: python

I recently installed the opencv package using pip install and I wrote a small code to test it (cvtest.py). The code runs through the python idle shell but running it though the command prompt gives the error

```
Error while finding module specification for 'cvtest.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'cvtest' while trying to find 'cvtest.py')
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both python and the package. looking up the system path using `python -m site` gives these results. I am the only user of my laptop.

```
sys.path = [
'C:\\Users\\Kareem Mostafa\\Desktop\\Assignments\\computer vision',
'G:\\Python37\\python37.zip',
'G:\\Python37\\DLLs',
'G:\\Python37\\lib',
'G:\\Python37',
'G:\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages',
```

This is the code I am using

```
import cv2
x=cv2.imread('backpack for sale.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('x',x)
```

update: the problem is happening with all the py files I am having whether they require imports or not. apparently python is looking for `_init_.py` for all the files as if they are packages. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 224):

For anyone else that had this problem (assuming kareemostafa has fixed it now!)

Removing the `.py` suffix on the `python -m` command fixes this problem, it appears `-m` only requires module names whereas running it directly as a python file (no `-m` option) requires the `.py` suffix

In your case `python -m cvtest` should be sufficient.

Comment: Same for me on a custom wrapper for windows command line (ConEmu) and your solution worked!

Comment: I have a nested structure and not using .py and still experiencing an error.

Comment: @s2t2 I got this error when running it in the wrong directory (it contained a file `aaa.py` with the same name as the package (directory) `aaa` I tried to run with `python -m aaa.bbb`. I changed the directory and it worked.

Comment: Strange, I've had this command work with `.py` suffix before.

Comment: Funny, at first it complained about the code content *in* the file and I could fix it in a couple of steps, thus, `python3 -m` obviously opens the file before execution. And in the end it still does not execute it just because of the filename suffix.