# Python Unit test module throws "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.test_file'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, anaconda

I'm trying to execute a test case for a project I've been working on. I used to successfully execute the unit tests earlier but it errors out now. I know for sure that there have been no updates to any libraries or change in the Path. I tried to look at the source code and figure out why it's erroring out but no luck yet. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Python version - 3.7.1

Sample Code below

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

def test_dummy(self):
    self.assertEqual(2+2,4)
```

I used the following command in cmd to execute the test.

`C:\Users\Yadada\Desktop\repo\mwe\mwe>python -m unittest tests\test_file.py`

My folder structure is

```
 MWE -|
      |_tests - |
                |_test_file.py
```

The expected output is the test being executing successfully because it's a straightforward one. But I end up getting the following error

```
strclass
ERROR: test_file (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yadada\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 156, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.test_file'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
```

Comment: do you have an `__init__.py` file in the `tests` directory to make them discoverable as part of the module?

Comment: Nope I don't, I never had the `__init.py__` file earlier in the same `tests` directory but the tests worked fine.

Comment: @aws_apprentice - I put an empty `__init__.py` file in the tests folder and surprisingly the unit test works now. I wonder why? Can you give a brief explanation about this behavior if you could? If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for will explain better than I can

Comment: I am having this error too, 
\_\_init\_\_.py is **not needed** in Python 3.3+ unless you need to run an installation script in that directory

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The issue got resolved after placing an empty `__init__.py` file in the tests folder.

For a better explanation about why it worked, refer to [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Thanks, @aws_apprentice for the help.

Comment: I'm getting this error on github actions, but not locally, and this did not solve it for me.

Comment: Did not work for me either.

Comment: `__init__.py` is not required in this case for python 3.3+
There is a different problem here

Answer (score 17):

With PyCharm 2020.2 the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named" error can also happen when running a unit test in a sub folder which imports a module from a parent folder under test. PyCharm is taking by default the script path for executing the test which fails e.g. with this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/home/foobar/projects/foo/mypythonproject/moduleundertest'
```

The solution is to edit the [run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-python-unit-test.html) of the unit test and change the Unittests Target from "Script path" to "Module name".

Comment: If running tests in a folder, for the target put the name of the folder, eg. `unit`

Answer (score 7):

The reason is some library is using the package name already, see:
[this stack overflow question about reserved package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066242/what-are-the-reserved-python-module-package-names)

To understand the poblem: rename the `tests` package to `tests_package` package. (`test` is also a reserved package name)

Before:

```
MWE -|
     |- tests -|
               |- test_file.py
```

After:

```
MWE -|
     |- tests_package -|
                       |- test_file.py
```

(Since python 3.3 the `__init__.py` is not required.)

Then running `python -m unittest tests_package\test_file.py`

Using a "venv" would solve it for `tests` package name but not for `test`

Probably an even more pythonic solution would be to not have your project run in "root" by giving it a unique module name, releasing you from the requirement to have a package name unused by python libraries for the `tests` directory.
example:

```
GitFolderOfProject -|
                    |- MWE -|
                            |- tests -|
                                      |- test_file.py
```

Then running the tests from the "GitFolderOfProject" as `python -m unittest MWE\tests\test_file.py`

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to add:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

to the bottom of my test file.

I was then able to run:

```sh
python -m <test-file>
```

---

Removing the `.py` suffix from my `python -m` command was also required:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817059/2743131) for details.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple setup magic.

First things first - in PyCharm:

1. Right-click on folder (in the project tree) with tests - mark this folder as "tests folder".
2. Right-click on folder (in the project tree) with sources - mark this folder as "sources folder".
3. Remove bad "Run configuration" (or don't remove, you choose).
4. Right click on on folder with tests (already marked as the "tests folder") - choose "run".

This is all. Really simple. Logical. It took me about an hour to find it out.

Comment: There was no mention of PyCharm in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Pycharm 2023.1 (detailed version below)

GitFolderOfProject -|
|- src-|
|- utests -|
|- test_file.py

I could run the test from command line from the /src folder

```
python -m unittest discover  .\utest\
```

However on the IDE , I got ModuleNotFound.

In addition to changing Script path to Module Path I had to change the
working directory of /utest folder to /src . I was able to run tests from the IDE.

PyCharm 2023.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-231.9161.41, built on June 20, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+10-b829.16 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2012M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv (3.2.0-231)

Answer (score 0):

Even after adding `__init__.py` and renaming my tests to django's naming conventions, I still had this error. My problem was the structure of the tests files was wrong.
I had

```
apps -|
      |- reports -|
                  |- tests -|
                            |- test_file.py
```

Where I should have added another package between the `tests` package and the `test_file.py` named as the app I am in, in my case `reports`. So the new structure is

```
apps -|
      |- reports -|
                  |- tests -|
                            |- reports -|
                                        |- test_file.py
```

I don't know why it has to be like this, though.